# html2canvas render only the visible part of div element

Tags: javascript, css, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas to screenshot a scrollable div element in the page.
However, it only renders the what is visible instead of whole div.

Here is a small example: https://codepen.io/johnhckuo/pen/abpGrmr

I've done some searching and see others recommend setting `scrollY: -window.scrollY` in the html2canvas parameter.
But it doesn't work for me.

Does anyone have experience on this issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a child element to #photo, which is not constrained by CSS - like this:

```
<div id="photo">
<div id = "photo-inner">
        <button onclick="takeshot()">
        Take Screenshot
    </button>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    Hello everyone! This is a
    trial page for taking a
    screenshot.
    <br><br>
    This is a dummy button!
    <button> Dummy</button>
    <br><br>
    Click the button below to
    take a screenshot of the div.
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="takeshot()">
        Take Screenshot
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Then, make the child element the target of html2canvas:

```
let div = document.getElementById('photo-inner');
```

(This works in your Codepen, which I can't fork, as I'm not signed up.)

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much. Is it because previously html2canvas is affected by the css attribute of #photo, so it only shows part of the div?

Comment: html2canvas is a bit strict on some CSS rules.  By adding a child div with no CSS, you allow it to get the full content.